# How to read excel files based on partial file names

Tags: r

How do I read excel files just based on the first part of the file name? For example my file is "File_01_01_2019", where "File" is always the same but the date changes often, so I would want to read excel files that start with "File" in this scenario.

Comment: Please give feedback about answers so the community knows whether the problem is solved or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you

```
library(readxl)
sapply(list.files(path = "your_path",
                  # regex that defines to start with "File" and ends with ".xlsx"
                  pattern = "^File.*\\.xlsx$",
                  full.names = TRUE), 
       read_excel)
```

Comment: I guess you have to check for the correct delimiter and stuff